# Explicit conversion to the same type

Tags: java, performance

Do explicit conversions to the same type impact performance or do they get filtered by the compiler and never reach the byte code?

Example:

```
int x = 3;
int y = (int) x;
```

Comment: Why you need to do this?

Comment: @HarryJoy I simply wonder about the the behavior of the compiler in such a weird situation, as it doesn't even produce a warning.

Comment: Did I really write conversation? HAHA! Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

running javap -c on this class:

```
public class SameTypeCastsDemo {

    public static void withoutCasts() {
        int x = 2;
        int y = x;
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public static void withCast() {
        int x = 2;
        int y = (int) x;
        System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```

shows that the bytecode looks identical:

```
public static void withoutCasts();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_2
   1:   istore_0
   2:   iload_0
   3:   istore_1
   4:   getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   7:   iload_1
   8:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   11:  return

public static void withCast();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_2
   1:   istore_0
   2:   iload_0
   3:   istore_1
   4:   getstatic   #2; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   7:   iload_1
   8:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
   11:  return
```

Update: with non-primitive object references:

```
public class SameTypeCastsDemo {
    Integer x;
    Integer y;

    public SameTypeCastsDemo(Integer x, Integer y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(y);
    }

    public static void withoutCasts() {
        SameTypeCastsDemo x = new SameTypeCastsDemo(2, 3);
        SameTypeCastsDemo y = x;
        y.print();
    }

    public static void withCast() {
        SameTypeCastsDemo x = new SameTypeCastsDemo(2, 3);
        SameTypeCastsDemo y = (SameTypeCastsDemo) x;
        y.print();
    }

}
```

javap -c SameTypeCastsDemo:

```
public static void withoutCasts();
  Code:
   0:   new #6; //class SameTypeCastsDemo
   3:   dup
   4:   iconst_2
   5:   invokestatic    #7; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   8:   iconst_3
   9:   invokestatic    #7; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   12:  invokespecial   #8; //Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
   15:  astore_0
   16:  aload_0
   17:  astore_1
   18:  aload_1
   19:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method print:()V
   22:  return

public static void withCast();
  Code:
   0:   new #6; //class SameTypeCastsDemo
   3:   dup
   4:   iconst_2
   5:   invokestatic    #7; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   8:   iconst_3
   9:   invokestatic    #7; //Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   12:  invokespecial   #8; //Method "<init>":(Ljava/lang/Integer;Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
   15:  astore_0
   16:  aload_0
   17:  astore_1
   18:  aload_1
   19:  invokevirtual   #9; //Method print:()V
   22:  return
```

Comment: Can I assume this would also apply to object references?

Answer (score 1):

Sun called it [identity conversion.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html)

--quote from the link --

> A conversion from a type to that same type is permitted for any type.
>
> This may seem trivial, but it has two practical consequences. First,
>   it is always permitted for an expression to have the desired type to
>   begin with, thus allowing the simply stated rule that every expression
>   is subject to conversion, if only a trivial identity conversion.
>   Second, it implies that it is permitted for a program to include
>   redundant cast operators for the sake of clarity.